# Is there a way to prevent Data.Generics.Alloy.GenInstances from scanning Data.Text.Internal?

Tags: haskell

I need to do transformations on an AST; here's a portion of the AST:

```
data Expr
  = BinExpr { beOp    :: BinaryOp
            , beLeft  :: Expr
            , beRight :: Expr }
  | Name Text
  | IntegerLit Integer
  | StringLit Text
  deriving (Data, Typeable)
```

And this is a fairly complex AST, so there are many types involved.

I'm using [alloy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/alloy-1.2.2) to generate the generic transformations, specifically:

```
autoGen :: IO ()
autoGen = do
  createDirectoryIfMissing True baseDir
  writeInstancesTo inst doc imports targetFile
  where
    inst = allInstances GenWithoutOverlapped
    doc = [genInstance (undefined :: Doc)]
    imports = header ++ instanceImports
```

Now, this was fine when using String, but I'm trying to migrate to Data.Text. When the code generation runs, it's reading into the internals of Data.Text like so:

```
instance (Alloy ([(GHC.Types.Char)]) (f :- ops) BaseOp) =>
     Alloy ((Data.Text.Internal.Text)) BaseOp (f :- ops) where
  transform _ ops (Data.Text.Internal.pack a0)
      =  Data.Text.Internal.pack
     (transform ops BaseOp (a0))
```

I believe `pack` is tied to GHC internals so that's not a valid pattern match, and regardless, having the code mucking with the internals of a Data.Text is liable to break the invariants. (Edit: it looks like there's an `instance Data Text where gfoldl f z txt = z pack`f`(unpack txt)` declaration, but regardless, I don't need/want to traverse Text values.)

Is there a way to force Alloy to treat a type as atomic? I'm hoping to avoid a newtype to wrap Text as all the code working with ASTs would need to deal with it, which rather defeats the purpose of using generics to avoid boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this trick: we parameterize the `Expr` type to override the `Data` instance used for `Text` when deriving instances with alloy.

```
data Expr_ text
  = BinExpr { beOp    :: BinaryOp
            , beLeft  :: Expr_ text
            , beRight :: Expr_ text }
  | Name text
  ...
  | StringLit text
```

The rest of the code base can use this synonym, hopefully without breaking too much with type inference issues.

```
type Expr = Expr_ Text
```

But for `Data`-generic operations, we use a `newtype` wrapper around `Text` and make it behave like a nullary constructor, hoping alloy doesn't need the result of `gunfold` (or perhaps you could make it behave like a string using pattern synonyms).

```
newtype DataText = DataText Text

instance Data DataText where
  gunfold _ f _ = f undefined
  ...
```

`autoGen` will then specialize everything at `DummyText`.

Use `Data.Coerce.coerce` to easily convert between functions on `Expr_ DataText` and `Expr`.

```
coerce :: Expr_ DataText -> Expr
coerce :: Expr -> Expr_ DataText
coerce :: (Expr_ DataText -> Expr_ DataText) -> Expr -> Expr
```

This might be used to write instances of alloy's type classes for `Expr`, based on the instances that were derived from you. It's a bit of boilerplate, but hopefully it can be contained and hidden without affecting the rest of the code.